# Automate creation of a VM with Docker containers running inside

Tags: docker, vagrant, openstack

I'd like to automate the creation of a Linux VM with two Docker containers inside of the VM running Oracle databases.

My idea was to:

1. Create a base image based on CentOS 7 in Packer with all the additional dependencies I need
2. Use this image in Vagrant + add shell provisioners to build and start docker containers on `vagrant up`.

This way it seems possible, but now the problem starts when I want to use OpenStack. I could create an OpenStack image in Packer but now I'm missing the Vagrant step that builds and starts containers... My goal would be to click `Launch Instance` in OpenStack and after a couple of minutes **have a VM that is running two Docker containers with databases with no additional manual steps**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [hypervisor docker driver for Openstack Nova Compute](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker). It is possible to manage docker containers as another VM (container format docker). You only need to provide the docker image in the provisioning scripts to launch the new instance.

Comment: But imagine I want to install Oracle RAC using containers. I need shared storage between containers, appropriate network config for private and public network. This I guess might be not easy in OpenStack while it's relatively easy to set up in a VM.

Comment: You can do it with Swift, but I got your point now. What you want is to do in near production env the same installation than vagrant up does. Then you can install a puppet server and configure the VM when launching the instance running the provision scripts during creation. See this link as an example https://start.nwt.fhstp.ac.at/blog/?p=236 probably there are more recent examples out there.

Comment: Actually I want to "emulate" a prod env inside a single VM - I want to have two networks between the containers, shared storage between containers running RAC. This is just for development purposes. I want exactly what this guy is doing here:
https://github.com/Seth-Miller/12c-rac-docker

In PROD I would have physical machines with real network connections etc.